# How to add google cloud monitoring datasource to grafana using a manifest in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, datasource, grafana, google-cloud-monitoring

I am trying to create a manifest where I will be able to add datasources to grafana deployed in kubernetes using a type datasource file like below.

```
    apiVersion: integreatly.org/v1alpha1
kind: GrafanaDataSource
metadata:
  name: google-cloud-monitoring-data-source
spec:
  datasources:
    - name: GCP_monitoring
      type: google-cloud-monitoring
      access: proxy
      editable: false
      isDefault: false
      jsonData:
        tokenUri: https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
        clientEmail: grafana@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com
        authenticationType: jwt
        defaultProject: my-project
      secureJsonData:
        privateKey: |
          -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
          .....
          -----END PRIVATE KEY-----
      version: 1
  name: google-cloud-monitoring-data-source.yaml
```

I changed the name stackdriver to google-cloud-monitoring. Not sure what name I can provide here. It is showing an error saying the datasource can't be found.
Does anybody know the id of the google cloud monitoring datasource?

Thanks.